# How can I calculate rank based on highest Score and lowest Minutes in MySql

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `teststatus` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `starttime` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `endtime` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `totaltime` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `totaltime_minutes` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `totalquestions` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `correctlyanswered` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `totalmarks` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emailid` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `requesttoken` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I have tried to excute this query.

```
SELECT d.userid, d.totaltime, d.totalmarks, d.emailid, c.ranks
FROM
(
    SELECT totalmarks, @rank:=@rank+1 Ranks
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT totalmarks
        FROM teststatus
        ORDER BY totalmarks DESC
    ) t,
    (
        SELECT @rank:= 0
    ) r
) c
INNER JOIN teststatus d
ON c.totalmarks = d.totalmarks
ORDER BY ranks;
```

but it shows rank based on totalmarks but i want rank based on maximum marks and less totaltime.

Result i am getting:

```
totaltime,totalmarks,ranks
150,13,1
180,12,2
110,11,3
100,11,3
105,11,3
80,11,3
120,11,3
90,11,3
140,9,4
112,8,5
145,8,5
120,7,6
157,7,6
120,6,7
```

Comment: What is "maximum marks"?

Comment: maximum marks is 15.

Comment: So in this case you want 80, 11 to be first and 90, 11 to be second and 100,11 to be third ... is it??

Comment: Please provide the expected output as well. that would help to analyse.

Comment: i am expecting out like : first it will calculate rank based on maximum totalmarks but if students have got same marks then i will calculate rank based less time taken by a student i.e totaltime .. for example :                       totaltime,totalmarks,ranks
150,13,1
    180,12,2
    80,11,3
90,11,3
100,11,3
105,11,3
110,11,3
120,11,3
140,9,4
112,8,5
145,8,5
120,7,6
157,7,6
120,6,7